# How to set classpath for multiple jars in command line?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

In this `jars` folder, I am having multiple jars. How to set classpath to all of these jars?

```
C:/users/jars/***
```

Comment: are you using eclipse?

Comment: I need to give it in command line itself.

Comment: You do it as it is has been documented for a long time now. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html . Look for 'Understanding class path wildcards'. Also look in the related items on the right side of this question.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/219801/1629362 answer

Comment: What is this mean? in the above questions...   java -cp "Test.jar;lib/*" my.package.MainClass

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: You don't have sense? Put the answer for my quiestion first and edit my question to say like already have an answer

Comment: What exactly do you think is different to this possible duplicate? For me it seems that it's totally the same. Thus, you shouldn't have asked this question as a simple search would have revealed the answer.

Comment: That is not the correct answer i m looking for .

Answer (score 0):

You can add this directory to classpath

```
java -cp C:/users/jars/* MAIN_CLASS_NAME
```

you can also use `-classpath` instead of `-cp`

Comment: I am getting USAGE...bla bla bla..